How to place a circle avatar on top of a sliverappbar and a column that contains other stuff using flutter
I was looking at this page design on uber eats app:

I'm just wondering how to make that circle avatar (domino logo) overlay on top of the sliver appbar and the rest of the contents using flutter.
My attempt is:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uber_eats_clone/view/components/restaurant_info_page_sliver_appbar.dart';

class PopupRestaurantPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PopupRestaurantPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<PopupRestaurantPage> createState() => _PopupRestaurantPageState();
}

class _PopupRestaurantPageState extends State<PopupRestaurantPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return [
            const RestaurantInfoPageSliverAppbar(),
          ];
        },
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 300,
                child: Text('w'),
              ),
              const Positioned(
                top: -20,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 35.0,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 20.0,
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/domino_logo.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

So I have a singleChildScrollView to control the rest of the page (excludes the appbar), and a stack that takes a container (for testing purpose), and the domino logo which I wrapped with a Position widget.
But this is what I got:

in which you can see that part of the circle avatar is hidden by the sliver appbar.
So if someone please can help me to solve this, thank you so much!

Hey peterparker! Have you find the solution?
